# Cutting numbers after the comma

Tags: c++

I have a trouble.
I'm trying to convert double number like this `4.66667` to `4.6`. I know that it can be done with `cout.precision` function, but I need to convert it, not print.

The whole idea is that I need to make some operations like `8/5`, and then cut numbers after the comma, leave just the `4.6`, put it in the new variable and request from the user to put exactly `4.6`.

If you have any idea, thank you very much.

Comment: Do you want to keep the datatype or have it converted to string? The exact number 4.6 might not be representable by a floating point type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use floor with a trick :

```
float rounded_down = floorf(val * 10) / 10;
```

(10 is to keep 1 decimal, 100 to keep two...)

Answer (score 0):

I have a function that I wrote for this.  The function takes doubles but you change change it if you need if you are using something bigger than a double.

```
double floorRound(double val, int places)
{
    return std::floor(val * std::pow(10.0, places)) / std::pow(10.0, places);
}
```